# Accessing Twitter with Akka Camel to return JSON

Tags: twitter, apache-camel, akka, akka-camel

I was using an HTTP POST method using the URL
"https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json" and in the body I was posting the key/value I wanted to get tweets from - for example "track=london". This was working fine.

Now I am trying to switch to AKKA-CAMEL and I am using their twitter consumer. I am using an endpoint URL of:

```
def endpointUri: String = s"twitter:////search?type=direct&keywords=${Settings.queryList()}&consumerKey=${tweeterCredentials.consumerKey}&consumerSecret=${tweeterCredentials.consumerSecret}&accessToken=${tweeterCredentials.accessToken}&accessTokenSecret=${tweeterCredentials.accessTokenSecret}"
```

I get a response from twitter but it is not in JSON and it is not the same information about the tweet as before. It just return the tweet text but before I was getting the whole metadata which I need to analyze.

Does somebody knows how to configure Camel URI to return JSON and the whole metadata as before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by using the following syntax:

```
def endpointUri: String = s"twitter://streaming/filter?type=event&keywords=${Settings.queryList()}&consumerKey=${tweeterCredentials.consumerKey}&consumerSecret=${tweeterCredentials.consumerSecret}&accessToken=${tweeterCredentials.accessToken}&accessTokenSecret=${tweeterCredentials.accessTokenSecret}"
```

Where: Settings.queryList return a comma separated list of keyworkds. The object tweeterCredentials holds the keys from Tweeter to access the site.

Also it is necessary to set autoAck like this in Camel:

> override def autoAck = true

This prevents a timeout exception.